# Generate random numbers of a chi squared distribution in R

Tags: r, chi-squared

I want to generate a chi squared distribution with 100,000 random numbers with degrees of freedom 3.

This is what I have tried.

```
df3=data.frame(X=dchisq(1:100000, df=3))
```

But output is not I have expected. I used below code to visualize it.

```
ggplot(df3,aes(x=X,y=..density..)) + geom_density(fill='blue')
```

Then the pdf looks abnormal. Please help

Comment: Try `rchisq(100000, df = 3)`

Comment: Thank you! can I know why dchisq does not work?

Comment: Straight from the help pages, `dchisq gives the density, ..., and rchisq generates random deviates.` dchisq was giving you the density for the points 1:100000 you specified rchisq is giving you 100000 random draws.  You may want to use `rchisq(n = 100000, df = 3)` which is clearer and identical to 1:100000 in outcome

Answer (score 3):

Use `rchisq` to sample from the distribution:

```
df3=data.frame(X=rchisq(1:100000, df=3))
ggplot(df3,aes(x=X,y=..density..)) + geom_density(fill='blue')
```

[image: resulting plot]

If your goal is to plot a density function, do this:

```
ggplot(data.frame(x = seq(0, 25, by = 0.01)), aes(x = x)) + 
  stat_function(fun = dchisq, args = list(df = 3), fill = "blue", geom = "density")
```

[image: resulting plot]

The latter has the advantage of the plot being fully deterministic.

Answer (score 1):

Use `rchisq()` to create a distribution of 100,000 observations randomly drawn from a chi square distribution with 3 degrees of freedom.

```
df3=data.frame(X=rchisq(1:100000, df=3))
hist(df3$X)
```

...and the output:

[image]

The ggplot version looks like this:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = df3, aes(X)) + geom_histogram()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You may use `rchisq` to make random draws from a random *X<sup>2</sup>* distribution as shown in the other answers.

`dchisq` is the density distribution function, which you might find useful though, since you want to plot:

```
curve(dchisq(x, 3), xlim=0:1*15)
```

[image]